# Как выровнять блоки по верхней границе?

Tags: html, css

Блоки с фиксированной высотой с inline-block.
Как прижать их к верхней границе контейнера без абсолютного позиционирования?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vertical-align: top;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`vertical-align: top;` работает если `display: table-cell;`
Можно родителю задать `display: flex; align-items: flex-start;`, 
но все зависит от того как у Вас сейчас построена сетка, если ввести flexbox просто так, может все поехать.

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` работает И для `display: inline-block;`